# How to fix issue cross thread when I use add controls in asynchronous? winform c#

Tags: c#, winforms

When I created new a control with asynchronous and add into other control.
It throw a exception as below.

Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'A2B2AA2D-059F-4ACD-B5E3-726FCE9FA1D0' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on."

How can I add new control inside a asynchronous function.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PVEZn.png)

Comment: From the thread that wants to add the control, call [`Control.Invoke()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.invoke?view=netcore-3.1) to call a method that actually adds it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Looks like you missed the part in the [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guidelines where it specifically says: **DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc.** - copy or type the text into the question.  You can edit your question to fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if (fileCanvas.InvokeRequired)
{
    fileCanvas.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate {
       fileCanvas.Controls.Add(canvas);
    });
}
else
{
    fileCanvas.Controls.Add(canvas);
}
```

This is easiest way to do it i guess.

Comment: Great, Thank you so much.